# Graylog with docker, how to configure the container

Tags: docker, linux-mint, graylog

Im completely new to both Graylog and Docker, and i cant solve the problem that i found stopping my progress. I followed the guides from official documentation [https://docs.graylog.org/en/4.0/pages/installation/docker.html] yet the problem appeared with:

> Request has been terminated
> Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.

From what i searched i need to change `http_enable_cors` to `true` value. I used this command:

```
sudo docker run --name graylog --link mongo --link elasticsearch \
-p 9000:9000 -p 12201:12201 -p 1514:1514 \
-e GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI="http://127.0.0.1:9000/" \
-d graylog/graylog:4.0 \
-e GRAYLOG_HTTP_ENABLE_CORS=true // already tried "true"
```

But it didnt really worked, hence i reach out to more experienced docker users.
Im (trying) using Graylog 4.0, and docker v20.10.5

Comment: Did you try this? -e GRAYLOG_HTTP_ENABLE_CORS="True"

Comment: No, it didnt worked

Comment: ok, change your last two lines, -d graylog/graylog:4.0 should be the last line. I'm not a perfect docker user, but everywhere I see that the image is the last parameter

Comment: it worked! Thanks! I didnt thought it was only a matter of changing lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last two lines like this:

```
sudo docker run --name graylog --link mongo --link elasticsearch \
-p 9000:9000 -p 12201:12201 -p 1514:1514 \
-e GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI="http://127.0.0.1:9000/" \
-e GRAYLOG_HTTP_ENABLE_CORS=true \
-d graylog/graylog:4.0
```

The image should be the last parameter.